# css z-index shadowed element in shadowed box

Tags: css

I'm having trouble getting an element with a shadow inside a box (also with a shadow). 
Any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/4T9Ac/

I think the trouble is with the `z-index` and position, but I can't quite put it together.

The rounded shadow must be behind the blue div, so that only the bottom shows at the bottom of the blue box. I want it to look like the "Single horizontal curve" in this demo: nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo

Note: the HTML structure must not change, if possible!

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div>
        <span class="btn-jaune">
            <a>
                <span>hola</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
section {
    border-top: 4px solid #00A1B1;
}
section > div {
    background-color: #E6F8FA;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
section > div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;

    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 10px;
    border-radius: 100px / 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.btn-jaune {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFEA00;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-jaune > a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 48px;
    display: block;
}
.btn-jaune > a:before, 
.btn-jaune > a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 49%;
    height: 20%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.btn-jaune > a:before {
    left: 4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
.btn-jaune > a:after {
    right: 4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
    transform: rotate(2deg);
}
.btn-jaune > a > span {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 17px 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

---

Iqbal I don't see any changes with the code from your answer. Got a jsfiddle link?

What I want to achieve is this:

[image: shadow]

Answer (score 1):

GOT IT!

The `:before` pseudo element went on the `section`, not on the `section > div`. 
Also, as Iqbal said, the `section` had to be in relative position.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/4T9Ac/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Short changes.**

```
section > div {
    position: relative;
    /*z-index: 1;*/
}
.btn-jaune {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.btn-jaune > a {
    background: #FFEA00;
}
```

**Long changes.**

```
section {
    position: relative;
}
section > div {
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*z-index: 1;*/
}
section > div:before {
    /*z-index: -2;*/
}

.btn-jaune {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
.btn-jaune > a {
    background: #FFEA00;
}
.btn-jaune > a:before,
.btn-jaune > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Warning: Negative z-index will not work in older browsers.

Comment: Almost! However, doing this we lose the shadow of the link element.
I'm beginning to think I did not quite well understand the z-index attribute, and that this is not possible at all.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% what you are wanting the final product to look like, but if you change `section > div:before` to have a `top: 5%;`, it puts the yellow box in the middle of the other box.

Comment: The rounded shadow must be behind the blue div, so that only the bottom shows at the bottom of the blue box.
I want it to look like the "Single horizontal curve" in this demo: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/